# c++ to csharp string passing with dllimport , lost accents

Tags: c#, c++, dll, utf-8, dllimport

I am trying to send a message from c++ to csharp but some of my accents are lost in the way ( not all of them?? ) ps: writing from italian

Here is what I do : 
c++:

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    DLL_API void __cdecl getResults(char* entry, wchar_t* result);
} 

[...]

void getResults(char* entry,wchar_t* result)
{
std::string str(entry);
std::string Stringresult= "héà" ;
std::wstring wsTmp(Stringresult.begin(), Stringresult.end());
const wchar_t* constChar = wsTmp.c_str();
swprintf(result, Stringresult.length(), constChar);
```

c# :

```
    [DllImport("libface.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void getResults([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string entry, StringBuilder res);



    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(2000);


        string entry = Console.ReadLine();
        getResults( entry,result);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: You need to start using a proper text encoding. A Unicode encoding UTF8 is generally preferred. UTF16 may be more convenient.

Comment: can you please explan how to do? thank you

Comment: There are plenty of examples around. Try some research.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem thanks to this link (that state that the problem is much more complicated that some persons may think .... ) :

http://blog.kutulu.org/2012/04/marshaling-utf-8-harder-than-it-ought.html

c++ code:

```
extern "C" {
    DLL_API char* __cdecl getResults(char* entry);
}
char* getResults(char* entry)
{
   std::string Stringresult= "hàé";
   char *cstr = new char[Stringresult.length() + 1];
   strcpy(cstr, Stringresult.c_str());
   return cstr;
}
```

c# code:

```
[DllImport("libface.dll" , EntryPoint = "getResults")]
private static extern IntPtr getResults([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string entry);

static void Main()
{
  var data = new List<byte>();
 var ptr = getResults("p");
 var off = 0;
 while (true)
 { 
    var ch = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, off++);
    if (ch == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
    data.Add(ch);
 }
  string sptr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.ToArray());
  Console.WriteLine(sptr);
```

Comment: No. This is a memory leak. And the C++ code doesn't yield UTF8 encoded data.

Comment: it works for me, i successfuly get my accents.  also i thought stackoverflow was about helping people not just telling them they are wrong.  I've spend hours looking for a solution so  no "There are NOT  plenty of examples around" that do what i want to do. So thanks for not helping , i hope my answer will help someone

Comment: It won't help anybody.